# MFC, Determine the drawText/TextOut is be covered by other window

Tags: mfc, drawtext, textout

I have develop a application, which user interface like a follow picture,

[Original Picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zgkh6yfm0ozf29o/1.jpg)

Now I open control panel window to covered the application window, like a follow picture,

[cover picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rg44ki90gn84fem/2.jpg)

when I close the control panel window,

[close contrl panel window](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a2saojlgwbsnm40/3.jpg)

the text which is use DrawText/TextOut function to paint,

will be erase,

How do I determine the situation, when the text be erase....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that your DrawText and other painting functionality is written in the wrong place. You must do it in OnPaint or OnEraseBkgnd so that they are always painted (when other window overlaps, on resizing etc).

Also, you must make sure that you are correctly creating (CreateDC) & releasing the device context (ReleaseDC) of each object.

Comment: Thanks your response. For now, I not necessary to repaint it frequently, so I use a flag to determine the repaint time, the drawtext/TextOut is define in onPaint. If I always repaint it, the windows will  lights flashing.

Comment: The WM_PAINT is processed only when necessary. When a window requires painting. It is not continuously run. So you shouldn't see the flashing. You can avoid using the flag. Windows will manage automatically when WM_PAINT must be queued & processed.